# How to select column where value equals?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to select the column where the value from a text input equals, i am being returned a value from the input and can echo it. But i cannot do a search and echo what column the value is in. i need to be able to echo the column name the value is in, and multiple if it is in more than one.
Any help is appreciated.

```
 $skw = $_POST['k'];
    if(isset($_POST['k'])){
    $connect = mysql_connect('*', '*', '*')or die('Could not execute command. Please contact a administrator.');
    mysql_select_db('*')or die('No database');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM *TABLE*
    WHERE A1 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR B1 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR C1 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR D1 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR E1 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR F1 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR G1 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR H1 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR I1 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR J1 LIKE '%$skw%'
    OR A2 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR B2 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR C2 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR D2 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR E2 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR F2 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR G2 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR H2 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR I2 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR J2 LIKE '%$skw%'
    OR A3 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR B3 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR C3 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR D3 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR E3 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR F3 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR G3 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR H3 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR I3 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR J3 LIKE '%$skw%'
    OR A4 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR B4 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR C4 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR D4 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR E4 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR F4 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR G4 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR H4 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR I4 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR J4 LIKE '%$skw%'
    OR A5 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR B5 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR C5 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR D5 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR E5 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR F5 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR G5 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR H5 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR I5 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR J5 LIKE '%$skw%'
    OR A6 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR B6 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR C6 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR D6 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR E6 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR F6 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR G6 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR H6 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR I6 LIKE '%$skw%' 
    OR J6 LIKE '%$skw%'";
    $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
        while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
     echo("<tr><td>$data[0]</td><td>$data[1]</td></tr>");
    }}
```

Comment: use mysql_fetch_array() insead of mysql_fetch_row()

Comment: This query makes me suspect you should be refactoring your database so that your [A-Z][0-9] columns become *rows* in a different table (accessible via a join).

Comment: use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead of mysql_fetch_row(). Also you should now stop using deprecated mysql_* instead try [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions.

Comment: @Quentin Was going to say the same, but could be that he's querying user options or something else where different values have similar input types.

Comment: @chiragode Thanks, I still get the same return, it just returns the first 2 values in the row.

Comment: @SweetieBelle — yes, but even so.

Comment: Your database isn't normalized, the *TABLE* design is a mess and will make you work hard for nothing. Google for "Database Normalization", redesign the table and this problem will sort out for itself.

Comment: @STTLCU You don't know that. Could be a search for a term against `keywords`, `title`, `description`, `author` on a perfectly normalized book database...

Comment: @BraedC You should look into [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) as it's designed for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @SweetieBelle All I'm trying to do is Search for an item in a column/row to find its location in a storage room.

Comment: @BraedC In that case, you probably should have 2 more tables. Google '3rd Normal Form'.

Comment: @SweetieBelle given the question asked, the apparent skill level of the OP and the column names (which have a pattern) I still say this isn't a normalized database. Anyway, even if the database was already normalized, it's better to point it out for other novice readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider normalizing your database so that all those fields A1 ... J6 are individual rows:

```
mytable_fields:
* field_ref (foreign key to mytable)
* field_nr
* field_value
```

Your query would then become:

```
SELECT field_nr, mytable.*
FROM mytable
INNER JOIN mytable_fields ON mytable.field_ref = mytable.id
WHERE field_value LIKE '%$skw%';
```

This is the only practical way you can tell which field contained the value you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

You should use show columns to get the column names, check the syntax below.

SHOW [FULL] COLUMNS {FROM | IN} tbl_name [{FROM | IN} db_name]
[LIKE 'pattern' | WHERE expr]

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UNION`, where each sub-query matches a single column, and outputs an additional column that says which column it's matching.

```
SELECT 'A1' AS Col, *
FROM Table
WHERE A1 LIKE '%$skw%'
UNION
SELECT 'B1' AS Col, *
FROM Table
WHERE B1 LIKE '%$skw%'
UNION
SELECT 'C1' AS Col, *
FROM Table
WHERE C1 LIKE '%$skw%'
...
```

If a row matches in multiple columns, it will turn into multiple rows in this result.